# Missing a Valid API Key for Youtube Data API v3 using Python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was trying to work with the Youtube API to collect video statistics from a channel (that I don't own) using the `requests` python library to make an API call and save it as a pandas dataframe.

```
# Import libraries
import requests
import pandas as pd

#  Keys
api_key = "Key generated by Google for me"
channel_id = "ID of any YouTube channel I want to explore" 

# make API call
ss_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key="+api_key+"&channelId="+channel_id+"&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=500"
ss_response = requests.get(ss_url).json()

ss_response
```

Each time I execute the above Python code it returns the following message:

> {'error': {'code': 403,
> 'errors': [{'domain': 'global', 
> 'message': 'The request is missing a valid API key.', 
> 'reason': 'forbidden'}], 
> 'message': 'The request is missing a valid API key.',
> 'status': 'PERMISSION_DENIED'}}

Can anybody help me resolve this error, please?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuM7KH-JLu8

Comment: @DaImTo Thank you for the link. I already crated and validated my YouTube Data API exactly they way shown in your shared link. I have successfully resolved the issue which was actually a typo issue.  Missed the '=' symbol after the  the '?key' in an attempt to pass through the API parameters in defining our url variable (ss_url).

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem with your API Key,
Check if your API key is validated, sometimes it takes time.
Re-send api key request and try a new one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found no problem with my API key validation. The problem is now resolved. I made a typo by NOT using '=' symbol right of the '?key' while attempting to pass through the API parameters in defining our url variable (ss_url).